# How do i configure IIS so that a websites internal links beginning with a slash "/" reference the root of the website not the root of the webserver

Tags: url, redirect, iis

I'm trying to implement URL redirecting in different websites hosted on my W10 IIS10 development PC and from searching SO i believe that internal links for JS and CSS files need to start with a forward slash e.g. ....src='/css/styles.css'
How do i configure IIS so that internal links beginning with a forward slash reference the root of the website rather than the root of the webserver

I've tried creating an application pool and configuring and attaching it to a site
Internal links in website starting with a forward slash still seem to be looking at the root directory of IIS rather than the root directory of the website
[Website within IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIpLc.png)

Comment: IIS has nothing to do with that. The actual interpretation of path is the responsibility of the web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

When using resources in a web project, you must specify a path for the resource. You can set the src attribute with a site root relative path, resolved against the site root. Site root-relative paths are useful if you keep resources used throughout your site, such as images or client-side script files, in folders located under the site root.

This article may help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178116(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN